# Blank screen appearing in android device when using intersecpter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The app is working fine when I try to run by ionic serve command but when i deploy the app in actual device blank screen appears.

code of intersecpter:

```
angular.module('DemoApp').factory('sessionInjector', function () {
    var sessionInjector = {
        request: function (config) {
            config.requestTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            response.config.responseTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
            return response;
        }
    }
    return sessionInjector;
});
```

I wasted my whole day figuring out the solution but still not able to resolve.

Comment: Something in the logs? Reload the app so you can see the error

Comment: There is no error in log its working perfectly in chrome but when I test it in actual device the blank page appears.

Comment: On which device are you deploying your app?